# Why cursor.moveToFirst() should be called while we using cursor?

Tags: java, android, cursor

Like the Title,I feel puzzled about that.                                                                                eg:

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
String [] projection ={Phone.NUMBER};
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int column = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
String num = c.getString(column);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cursor you get from `query` starts out *before the first record*.

So in order to use it, you need to put it somewhere.